# Subscribe to ionic 3 event in vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic3

I want to execute some vanilla JavaScript code(in external file), When an ionic event is publish.
But i don't know how to do this. I want something like this.

**Typescript**

```
this.event.publish('TestEvent',{data:123});
```

**JavaScript**

```
 document.addEventListener("TestEvent", function(data) {
            alert('TestEvent');
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could just trigger the event again on `document`:

**TS:**

```
this.event.publish('TestEvent', {data:123});

const event = new CustomEvent('TestEvent', {detail: {data: 123}});
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

**JS:**

```
document.addEventListener('TestEvent', function (event) {
    alert('TestEvent');
    console.log(event.detail.data); // prints 123
});
```

More about custom events on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent

Comment: sorry, my bad, will update my answer. you need to wrap the payload in another object...